# What's it called when all the instruments cut out and only the vocals continue and then the instruments return?

Tags: voice

This is one of my favourite techniques within music (if it even is one). As such I would love to know what its called, thanks :)

Comment: Acapella? And after, tutti?

Comment: Or tacet for orchestra?

Comment: @Tim  minor nit:   A  capella ; two words.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - many thanks. I just missed the space bar! Minor nit : ca**p**ella - source - she-goat. Actually a bright yellow star. Ca**pp**ella - source - chapel. Wearing that pointy hat again...

Comment: I use the term Vocal Break. Not sure where I picked the term up, maybe recording class.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a musician, "tacet" ("silent") or "rest". If you're the vocalist, "a cappella" ("in the manner of the chapel").

If you're a sound engineer looking at a soundboard, you "solo" the channel (after the name of the button on the vocalist's channel on the board). This is very rare unless you're doing live looping and are doing your own sound.

Comment: Vocalists are musicians.  At least some of them are.

Comment: @phoog "musician who uses their voice" is a bit of a mouthful

Comment: I'm not objecting to the use of "vocalist" to refer to the singers; I'm objecting to the use of "musician" to refer to the instrumentalists.

Answer (score 1):

This was posted 3 years ago, so I am sure you've found an answer by now (though I don't see one that feels right, I'm here looking for one too) but me and all my music friends call it a "false drop"! When it's a big full sound, the whole band, and then the band stops but the vocalist continues and you think they're going to end the song but then the whole band comes back in again!